# Only the first created button works in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make the "close-circle" button work. this function will create the button multiple times if there are multiple items, each of them is created with a specific id, and once it is clicked, will delete all the data based on that id. Somehow ONLY the first created button works, the rest just do nothing. I believe there is something wrong with the way of creating the `addEventListener`.

```
if (inCartItem) {

    productsContainer.innerHTML = '';
    // item means each item in the object which is the inCartItem
    Object.values(inCartItem).map(item => {

        productsContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class ="product-incart">
        <ion-icon id ="${item.Id}CloseBtm" name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
        <img src="${item.src}">
        <span>${item.Productname}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="price-incart">$${item.Price}</div>
    <div class="quantity">
    <ion-icon name="caret-back-outline"></ion-icon>
        <span>${item.inCart}</span>
        <ion-icon name="caret-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="total">
    $${item.inCart * item.Price},00
    </div>
                `
        console.log(item.Id);
        document.getElementById(item.Id + "CloseBtm").addEventListener("click", ("click", () => { removeAll(item); }));

    })
```

Comment: Why did you use ````"click"```` twice in your ````eventListener````?

Comment: Rather surprising that the _first_ button is supposed to work with this - it should rather be the _last_? With `.innerHTML += …`, you are _re-creating_ all elements contained in the container each time. So each time, all event handlers you had bound to the already existing buttons, will be lost (because those buttons get re-created), and only the last button you added, will get an event handler added at the very end of your loop body.

Comment: @michaelT because without that it will just call the function right the right ( like clicking all the button. once it is created)

Comment: @GabrielLam That's... not how it works. You've misunderstood something.

Comment: @CBroe each of the buttons with a specific id ( id ="${item.Id}CloseBtm"), so wonder if it will bound to the already existing buttons.

Comment: @GuyIncognito haha yes I am new, I used the way of adding event Listener for another part works fine, but it is creating inside a for loop, instead of an if statement like this. so I think that might be the problem?

Comment: It _got_ bound to the specific button you generated in the current loop iteration. But that button gets _replaced_, when you do `.innerHTML += …` in the next iteration. The browser creates the elements by re-parsing what the current innerHTML of the container already contained, plus what you newly added. But since those buttons do not contain event handling in the HTML code itself, you get “new” buttons replacing the already existing ones, that are now missing the event handler. You should go read up on _event delegation_, that is a common method to deal with dynamically added elements.

Comment: @CBroe yes you are right, thanks for the explanation! helps a lot !